# Rigorous Development of Relational Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Can anyone suggest a text that provides a rigorous and modern development of the relational algebra? A chapter out of a rigorous survey text on algebra, for example, would probably be sufficient. In any event, such a treatment may presume (and, ideally, will presume) that basic aspects of algebra such as groups/rings/modules/etc. are familiar. Unfortunately, the only treatments of relational algebra I've been able to find are very elementary and directed at RDBMS programmers.

Comment: Have you find something else except the  Maddux's work?

Comment: @Yrogirg Sorry but, no, I have not. Seems like there's a definite lack of pedagogical material in this area. As it turns out, Maddux wrote a huge treatise (over 700 pages) on the subject but this is considerably more than I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nice entry point into the literature on calculus of relations is Roger D. Maddux's [The Origin of Relation Algebras in the Development and Axiomatization of the Calculus of Relations.](http://orion.math.iastate.edu/maddux/papers/Maddux1991.pdf) This historical survey will take you from the pioneering work of Pierce and Schröder up to more recent work by Jonsson, Lyndon, Monk, Tarski and others. Chasing references to the works in the bibliography will lead you to more recent work.

Also see Uta Priss' [An FCA interpretation of Relation Algebra](http://www.upriss.org.uk/papers/fcaic06.pdf) for (pointers to) connections of relation algebra and the relational algebra in database theory.

Comment: _A remark, copied from the suggested edit:_ Also see Uta Priss' [An FCA interpretation of Relation Algebra](http://www.upriss.org.uk/papers/fcaic06.pdf) for (pointers to) connections of relation algebra and the relational algebra in database theory.

Comment: Bill, first link just takes you to Prof Maddux' page with no visible reference to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading through Jonsson and Tarski's "Boolean Algebras with Operators" Part II. As for a more modern reference: Givant is currently finishing up a book. I'd wait until he completes it.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the book "Database Systems" by Hector Garcia Molina et al. It's free online

https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Garcia-Molina-Database-Systems-The-Complete-Book-2nd-Edition/PGM2429.html

It may not be quite deep in terms of the Relational Algebra itself, but I
recommend it since it describes it in the context of query processing and optimization.